# Javascript focus on div while showing alert box

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

What I am trying to do is create a sequence of alert pop-ups that will be used as a tutorial for learning a websites' functionalities. The pop-ups will appear one after another explaining what each "div" of the website does. When a pop-up appears I want the referenced "div" to be focused ( brought to foreground ) so that it would be more visible.

The code looks like this and obviously it does not work:

```
var someDiv = document.getElementById('someID');
someDiv.focus();

alert("Message explaining functionality");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How can `alert()` and `div` have `focus` at the same time? You can call `alert()` with message, then call `focus` on element when `alert()` is closed.

Comment: An alert is the wrong mechanism if yiu want shared focus. All major browser implementations it blocks interaction from the site, besides it looks  terrible. You'd be better implementing your own notification box which you position next to each element your giving info on. .

Comment: No one likes alerts.

Answer (score 6):

To make a div focusable you've to use `tabindex` :

```
<div id='someID' tabindex='1'>MY DIV TEST</div>
```

Also try to give it a while to `focus` using `setTimeout`.

**NOTE :** I suggest really the use of another "flexible" modal plugin than the `alert()`.

Hope this helps.

```js
var someDiv = document.getElementById('someID');
someDiv.focus();

setTimeout(function(){
  alert("Message explaining functionality");
},10)
```

```html
<div id='someID' tabindex='1'>MY DIV TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with this to make your tutorial. I already made once something similar. [Check project here](http://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/http://).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      // Initialize the plugin
      $('#my_popup').popup();

    });
```

```html
<button class="my_popup_open">Tutorial</button>
<!-- Content of popup -->
<div id="my_popup">
I'm Tutorial
<button class="my_popup_close">Close</button></div>

  <!-- Include jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include jQuery Popup Overlay -->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay/1.7.13/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>
```